# Meteor - FlowRouter - Blank pages

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

Hey guys I'm doing a tutorial on extending the users class, 
[Link](https://medium.com/all-about-meteorjs/extending-meteor-users-300a6cb8e17f#.he8ievh3j) to the tutorial1
In every path I try, i always get a blank page, and i'm not understanding why.
Any help would be appreciated.
This is my routes.js file:

```
FlowRouter.route('/', {
   name: 'home',
   action: function() {
   BlazeLayout.render("mainLayout", {
      content: "home"
   });
  }
});
FlowRouter.route('/login', {
   name: 'login',
   action: function() {
   BlazeLayout.render("mainLayout", {
      content: "login"
   });
  }
});
FlowRouter.route('/register', {
   name: 'register',
   action: function() {
   BlazeLayout.render("mainLayout", {
      content: "register"
   });
  }
});
```

And this is my main-layout.html

```
<template name="mainLayout">
    {{>Template.dynamic template=content}}
</template>
```

Here is a link to my repo: https://bitbucket.org/mmrj9/hubapp/src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's some other issues on the pages that cause the problems. The use of `flow-router` is fine. They renders well with static HTML nodes.

Say, the reduced version of your home page,

```
<template name="home">
    Home Page.
</template>
```

, render the string on the client side as expected.

Would not make a list of the issues here, but hope this sheds some light on it for you to get going.

Comment: <li><a href="{{pathFor 'register'}}">Click here to register</a></li>

Comment: the problem seems to be here

Answer (score 1):

Have you defined your other templates?

e.g. The home template

```
<template name="home">
    {{#with currentUser}}
    <div class="ui raised segment">
        <h1 class="ui header">Current User</h1>
        <p>First Name: {{profile.firstName}}</p>
        <p>Last Name: {{profile.lastName}}</p>
        <p>Profile Picture: <img class="ui small circular image" src="{{profile.profPicture}}" /></p>
        <p>Organization: {{profile.organization}}</p>
    </div>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```